# Time period of oscillations of a point about the function's minimum value?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, mathematical-physics

How am I to go about the following problem? Please do not explicitly solve it.

> Let $E_0$ be the value of the potential function at the minimum point $\xi$. Find the time period $T_0=\lim_{E\to E_0}T(E)$ of small oscillations in the neighborhood of the point $\xi$.

Comment: Hint: the bottom of a potential well usually looks like a parabola.

Comment: you will need to know something about the shape of the potential function, the minimum energy is not enough information

Comment: @achillehui should I assume that the potential at $V(\xi\pm\delta)$ is at a maximum?

Comment: Nope, for smooth potential, we have $V(x) \approx V(\xi) + \frac12\left.\frac{d^2V(x)}{dx^2}\right|_{x=\xi} (x-\xi)^2$ when $x$ near $\xi$. The problem of computing the period reduces to one for a simple harmonic oscillator.

Comment: @achillehui Ah I understand, thanks a lot!